# Android- Code Error after running a few day later

Tags: java, android, xml

[image]I run my application and saw xml files were swapped with java and vice versa.
and my android manifest have this code. I don't know what happeded

> ����   4 �
>    � � � abc_action_bar_title_item I 
>   ConstantValue   abc_action_bar_up_container  abc_action_menu_item_layout  abc_action_menu_layout 
>   abc_action_mode_bar  #abc_action_mode_close_item_material 
>   abc_activity_chooser_view
>
> ## abc_activity_chooser_view_list_item  $abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material
>
> abc_alert_dialog_material      abc_alert_dialog_title_material 
>        abc_cascading_menu_item_layout  abc_dialog_title_material
>    abc_expanded_menu_layout 
>        abc_list_menu_item_checkbox  abc_list_menu_item_icon
>    abc_list_menu_item_layout  abc_list_menu_item_radio 
>   !abc_popup_menu_header_item_layout 
>   abc_popup_menu_item_layout  abc_screen_content_include 
>   abc_screen_simple  %abc_screen_simple_overlay_action_mode 
>   abc_screen_toolbar  $abc_search_dropdown_item_icons_2line 
>   abc_search_view  abc_select_dialog_material 
>   abc_tooltip  activity_login
>       activity_main  activity_signup  !cast_expanded_controller_activity  cast_help_text
>   cast_intro_overlay ! cast_mini_controller "
>   !cast_tracks_chooser_dialog_layout #
>   %cast_tracks_chooser_dialog_row_layout $
>   design_bottom_navigation_item % design_bottom_sheet_dialog &
>   design_layout_snackbar ' design_layout_snackbar_include (
>   design_layout_tab_icon ) design_layout_tab_text *
>   design_menu_item_action_area + design_navigation_item ,
>   design_navigation_item_header - 
>   design_navigation_item_separator . 
>   design_navigation_item_subheader / design_navigation_menu 0
>   design_navigation_menu_item 1 design_text_input_password_icon
>   2 fragment_addressing_system 3 mr_cast_dialog 4 m

Comment: Something must of happened. Did you upgrade anything? Move project files?

Comment: I faced the same issue in November 2018. And the most surprising thing was git was unable to detect it. Even local history didn't helped. Finally I cloned a new repository at a different location and kept the corrupted workspace as it is so that i can experiment with it and fix it. Today on reading this question I opened the corrupted workspace and was amused to see everything fine. Looks like it never got corrupted. Why the workspace got corrupted? How git was unable to detect it? How the corrupted workspace got fixed? is a mystery to me.

Comment: @MonishKamble I tried as you said and sandeep. And it worked. Thank you
I don't know why people are devoting my question. I tried my best but could not find any similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have backup of your project than Put your project source code somewhere else (Another drive) and open project from newly created location.

Same problem i fixed yesterday by this way. here is my code that was encrypted in another format.

[image]

Hope it solve your problem also.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Do you have any idea what was causing error

Comment: i also don't what is the reason for getting this error and why it's solved by changing directory.

Answer (score 0):

from the left panel in your android studio , `Right Click` on your file and choose `local History` menu . if those changes made recently you can get you file's content back by going through history.

If history is empty , than there is nothing you can do.!